# Unit Distance structure of Hoffman Singleton graph

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-geometry

This question has been bugging me since last 3 years.

Prove or disprove that Hoffman Singleton is an unit distance graph in $\mathbb R^2$. For those who are new to unit distance graphs, A graph is said to be unit distance if all its edges are unit length long.

This question just needs good visualization skills and can be even solved by a clever undergrad. Still, it eludes me.

Comment: There are known unit-distance embeddings of the Heawood Graph (none particularly nice), the Petersen graph, and the Coxeter graph. Whether the odd-4 graph and the Sylvester Graph are unit-distance is unknown. The existence of HS as unit distance seems unlikely.

Comment: I also feel that HS doesn't have a unit distance structure. But proving that a graph doesn't have a unit distance structure turns out to be real hard. All I do is search for some forbidden structure like $Q_3-e$, or see if some algebraic property is violated. I have tried with all known constructions of HS for ex. [const](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/Hoffman-Singleton.html). But still can't figure it out. And thanks for replying (thought - and been told - this part of maths is dying). Highly appreciate Numb3rs and your works.

Comment: I thought of using the Hadwiger–Nelson problem 7 coloring of the plane. Toss a UD HS onto it. Then by the pigeonhole principle, at least one color will get 8 vertices.  But that's okay, one color could get up to 15 vertices. Can we prove that the UD HS would always cover all 7 colors?

Comment: Sir, turns out that HS has a chromatic number 4. A construction can be found in the last part of this [paper](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3yXbZdzrE9cNjAxVGt0cGJJOUU/edit?usp=sharing), accepted by JCMCC. Color (1,2,3,4) has (15,15,10,10) vertices respectively. Still, using the pigeonhole principle in analyzing such problems is definitely a novel idea for me. Thanks for that.

Comment: Use the triplets/Fano HS. Then 15 Fanos, 15 triplets with 7, 10 triplets with 6, and 10 other triplets.  With 4 heavily overlapping vertices, HS is a unit distance graph in 3-space as a tetrahedron.  So... possibly the UD HS would fit into 4 hexagons of the Hadwiger-Nelson 7-coloring of the plane, with a 15-15-10-10 distribution. Can this case be ruled impossible? Any oddities/impossiblities if the hypothetical UD HS is moved around?  Also -- we have a boring 3-space embedding (the tetrahedron). Is there an embedding without overlapping vertices?

Comment: @Ed Pegg Sir, I am trying to follow your approach. Still it turns out to be hard while dealing with 50 vertices. Rather I am concentrating on the [odd 4 graph](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338069/is-the-odd-4-graph-a-unit-distance-graph-without-vertex-overlap) you posted.

Comment: One idea worth trying -- Build the 3D HS tetrahedron.  Let the edges have a range of length .9 to 1.1.  Then give the vertices a repulsive force in some sort of modelling program, and see what happens.  If it can expand out from a tetrahedron in some way, that new structure may give insight.