# Is the Odd-4 graph a unit-distance graph without vertex overlap?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Take the 35 triples of 1-7, from 123 to 567, as vertices. Connect vertices with no shared numbers to get the Odd-4 graph.  Let set A be the vertices with 7, set B be the vertices with 6, and let set C be the other vertices.  Unit equilateral triangle ABC is now a unit-distance embedding of the Odd-4 graph with heavy vertex overlap.

Is there a unit-distance embedding of the Odd-4 graph without vertex overlap?  The Coxeter graph is a subgraph, and a unit-distance embedding is known.  Odd-4 is a subgraph of the Hoffman-Singleton graph, which has an unknown UD status.

Comment: I strongly believe that this odd-4 graph has a UD structure. Lesser the number of edges more is the chance of UD structure. Since odd-4 graph has |E|=2|V|. Hence, less restrictions. Trying to extend the logic used to find the UD structure of Coxeter graph.

Comment: How about Robertson's (4,5)-cage.  Is that a unit distance graph?

Comment: For the Robertson (4,5)-cage, you'll first need a 12 cycle. Start with points x=1-12 on a unit circle. Change their distance to the origin to {a,b,c,d} based on whether mod(x,4) equals {0,1,2,3}.  Color the points in 3 colors based on mod(x,3). 
Pick {a,b,c,d} so that

Comment: 1. Each color on a unit circle.

Comment: 2.  Distance from x  to x+1  OR  x to x+4  is 1